# Installing Xen on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, grub, xen

I'm doing my first ever installation of Xen, and while the documentation is pretty extensive, I haven't found any thing appropriate to Ubuntu 9.10 anywhere.

Basically, in the past it seems you would edit the GRUB menu in menu.lst. In 9.10 GRUB2 did away with menu.lst and replaced it with grub.cfg which isn't supposed to be written to, rather you run the update-grub script.

I'm on my TA's computer so I really don't want to mess up anything. Has anyone installed Xen on Ubuntu 9.10 yet? I've installed the packages but am having difficulty getting the xen kernel into the list on reboot.

Comment: If anyone looks at this question later and is interested, here are some thoughts on xen on ubuntu 9.1: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1330481

Comment: So, if you plan to try out Xen ..... what do you do ? Fedora, Mint, Suse, BSD ??? .....

Answer (score 1):

XEN is so intimately bound up with the kernel that it is not a good idea to try to install it on any Linux that does not have an official package for it.

When I want to run XEN on Linux, I install OpenSUSE, select the kernel with XEN support, install the XEN package, and then I manage XEN through the usual OpenSUSE sysadmin GUI. The command line tools for managing XEN are there too.

In my opinion, you should get to understand XEN first using something like OpenSUSE before you attempt to patch it into another distro of Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to such an old question. It's good info to have here that OpenSUSE is a good option for a beginner's introduction to XEN.